# Ignoring records for certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, duplicates

I have data as below,

| ACCOUNT | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| asdf | 1 |
| asdf | 2 |
| asdf | 3 |
| kjhj | 1 |
| qwer | 1 |
| qwer | 1 |

need to get output:

| ACCOUNT | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| kjhj | 1 |
| qwer | 1 |

situation is that need to get records that have only "1" in 2nd column. If they have any other value other than "1", need to ignore all records for particular 1st column.
can you plz suggest a query

tried group by but didn't find option

Comment: Hint:  Use a HAVING clause.

Comment: Do you only have two columns in your real data? *(If you tried a query, include it here and explain what the problem with it was. Include any errors, problematic results, etc)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group to a single account per output row, then assert that all rows in a group must have flag=1 by using HAVING with *both* min and max.

```
SELECT
  account,
  MIN(flag)   flag
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  account
HAVING
      MIN(flag) = 1
  AND MAX(flag) = 1
```

Some people prefer the following and being more understandable, and it also causes a NULL row to exclude the group...

```
HAVING
  MIN(CASE WHEN flag=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```